# Kivy settings panel removes text property value from button widgets

Tags: python, kivy

I have come across an issue with the Kivy settings panel, when I open and close the panel, the text properties of my button widgets are cleared, even though they still display correctly.

The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        widget = Button(text='Hello World')
        widget.bind(on_release=self._button_callback)
        return widget

    def _button_callback(self, button):
        debug_string = f'{hex(id(button))}:{type(button.text)}:{button.text}'
        print(debug_string)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
```

When the program is run a window with a single button is displayed. The display text is "Hello World", clicking on this button produces the following

```
0x172aba17ed0:<class 'str'>:Hello World
```

If I then press F1 and open the default Kivy setting panel, then close the panel (making no changes to the settings options) and press the button again, I get the following:

```
0x172aba17ed0:<class 'str'>:
```

This seems a bit strange to me, why has the text property of the button been overwritten ? The text displayed on the button remains consistent.

This example was run using Python 3.10.4 (64bit) and Kivy 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Missing import of class SettingWithSpinner from kivy.uix.settings, related to [python settings freezes GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099115/python-kivy-settings-frezzes-gui-to-be-updated-value-from-button-widgets).

Without the import, no errors where reported at runtime and the bug is present, including the import seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).